# Wheel event not listening while leaving iframe

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome

I'm listening to both `window` and `iframe.contentWindow` and for some reason, if I'm triggering wheel event with `command` key inside the iframe while moving the cursor out of iframe, I don't get the events..
to be clear, it's happening when the cursor leaves the iframe

To be clear, it's happening on control+wheel (or pinch to zoom)

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <iframe id="frame" srcdoc="{`" <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head> </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Content inside an iframe, who knew...</h1>
        </body>

        </html>
        `}>
    </iframe>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```js
const log = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e);
};
window.addEventListener("wheel", log, { passive: false });
document
  .getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]
  .contentWindow.addEventListener("wheel", log, { passive: false });
```

In the video, whenever the browser zooms in, it wont pass the event so I can't prevent default behavior (zoom) and the "e" in the console is whenever wheel event is captured, it logs "e"
[Video to example](https://youtu.be/o64TxFTi_H0)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. What exactly means "_triggering_" in this context? Are you triggering the event programmatically, or by rolling the mousewheel?

Comment: its happening when command/control is down

Comment: added example to post.. thx :)

Comment: But isn't CTRL + mousewheel a zooming command? It actually doesn't matter, I still can't reproduce the issue. I've set up a test, attached `wheel` event to `window` on the main page and to `iframe.contenWindow`, the event fires on both windows when rolling the wheel, no matter CTRL is pressed or not.

Comment: In the video it looks like the event would fire, you can see `e` logged on a single line, the number in front of it changes every time the event fires. The only odd thing is, that the page actually is zooming, it shouldn't when you're canceling the default action.

Comment: Look at the video... I guess its showing on pinch mostly (trackpad)..
In my app it increases/decreases size of iframe and when the iframe's decrease, the cursor get out of bounds of iframe and then it stucks

Comment: In my test I've exactly the same code as you've in your example, and the issue can't be reproduced. Chrome or Firefox doesn't zoom the page, though. Maybe this is something related to your OS? (I'm testing on Windows).

Comment: did you try using trackpad to test?

Comment: I didn't but I can try ...

Comment: tried again, it's not firing the event when it's zooming

Comment: Still no repro on Windows with the trackpad, zooming doesn't take a place, and the event fires as expected.

Comment: https://youtu.be/mISj_XWx_dc
tried on windows

Comment: @Teemu any ideas?

Comment: Like I said, I can't reproduce the issue. It's strange, that your page is still zooming, as passing `passive: false` to the event and `e.preventDefault()` should prevent the zooming. That behavior of the trackpad might be even device dependent ..?

Comment: can we try google meet and I'll show you?

Comment: It's not worth of it, I saw the behavior in your videos, and I can't explain that, because the same code works fine when run on my local server. Maybe the trackpads in the devices you're using are somehow overriding the browser behavior, you could take a look at the settings of the trackpads ..?

Comment: tried on linux from different computer and still problematic...
use pinch on trackpad while moving the cursor with mouse

Comment: Uhh ... I've tried pinching and scrolling the mousewheel, moving the mouse out of the iframe and back again, with and without CTRL, no repro, the page is just not zooming. The only way I get the browser to zoom is to use CTRL + + and CTRL + - keys, those are expectedly not firing a mousewheel event, though.